# a vs a:link, What is the difference?

Tags: css, css-selectors, anchor, pseudo-class

What is the differences between `a {...}` and `a:link{...}`?

Are there different usages, and benefits between them?

Comment: Just a small point - the :link is a pseudo-selector. There is only one `a` tag.

Comment: `a:link` is a pseudo class while `a` is base HTML anchor tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: a:link vs just a (without the :link part)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638229/css-alink-vs-just-a-without-the-link-part)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) `a:link` is for not visited, `a:visited` is for visited, and just `a` applies to both.

Comment: You're spot on. I don't know why this wasn't marked as answered already.

Comment: This is not correct: `a:link` is for anchor tags that are links (have an `href`) attribute. `a` affects all anchor tags. (See, e.g., http://jsbin.com/uxuyum/1/)

Comment: @futuraprime that's not true either.  It's more correct to say that :link only applies to anchor tags that have a href attribute and are not visited, active, or hover.  This is extremely important as it means styles applied with a:link no longer apply once a link have been visited, is hovered, or is active.

Comment: No, link styles continue to be applied on hover/visited (at least in Chrome): http://jsbin.com/uxuyum/3 — if you hover over the link, it remains in sans-serif. It's of equal precedence with :hover & etc.

Answer (score 14):

`a` covers all the bases. `a:link` is used only if the link in un-`visited`, un-`hover`ed, and in-`active`.

So, use `a` for things like font-family (if you want links to come up in a different font), then use `link` for the standard formatting, and `visited`, `hover` and `active` for 'special effects'.

**EDIT:** After reading Sander's [W3C link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes), I can see that I didn't have it quite right. `a:link` will cascade down to `a:hover` and `a:active`, i.e. anything in `a:link` that is not over-ridden by the dynamic pseudo-classes will also apply to them.

Comment: Hmm interesting edit, I didn't catch that one to be honest :-)

Answer (score 6):

`a:link` only affects links that have a href attribute basically (if a:visited, a:hover or a:active does not apply)... The main case where I've noticed a difference is that `a:link` doesn't affect [Named Anchors](http://www.dwfaq.com/Tutorials/Basics/named_anchors.asp) whereas `a` will.  Also, `a` is the default style if none of the other pseudo classes are defiend.

```
<a name="Section1">Section 1</a>
```

Comment: Actually, a named anchor is visible (provided it has content).

Comment: Yeah, <a name="Section1">Section 1</a> is an example of where a:link will not affect the style.

Comment: Woops, I accidentally removed that one. Yeah I agree that they can have content, and you could use css on `a` to change the style. It's not true thought that everything with an href is affected by `a:link`

Comment: Yeah I guess I phrased that wrong.  a:link will not affect anchors that don't have a href I should say.