# CSS: a:link vs just a (without the :link part)

Tags: css, anchor, pseudo-class

So we're required to use the following order for CSS anchor pseudo-classes

```
a:link    { color: red }    
a:visited { color: blue }  
a:hover   { color: yellow } 
a:active  { color: lime }
```

But my question is why bother with the a:link part? Rather, is there any advantage to the above (other than perhaps clarity) over:

```
a { color:red; } /* notice no :link part */
a:visited { color: blue; }
etc.,etc.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:link` selects unvisited links, that is: anchors with an `href` attribute which have not been visited by the browser (for whatever definition the browser vendor has for "visited").

If it has `:link` then it will never match `<h1><a name="foo">A foo to be linked to</a></h1>`

(Although you should be using `<h1 id="foo">A foo to be linked to</h1>` these days.)

Aside from that, it does make it clearer what it is for.

```css
a         { color: orange }
a:link    { color: blue }    
a:visited { color: indigo }  
a:hover   { color: green } 
a:active  { color: lime }
```

```html
  <a>my anchor without href</a>
  <br><br>
  <a href="http://somelinkhere.com">my anchor without href</a>
```

(They also have different levels of [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity))

Comment: can you explain the stops it matching part a bit more please? Not sure I understand.

Comment: `a` matches all anchors. `a:link` matches anchors that are unvisited links. `a:visited` matches anchors that are visited links. `<a name="foo">` is an anchor that is not a link of any kind.

Comment: @Quentin: Really? I cannot find that in the specs.

Answer (score 8):

Just "a" refers to ALL possible links (unvisited, visited, hovered, and active), whereas "a:link" just refers to normal unvisited links.

If you use "a" instead of "a:link", you are setting the default CSS for ALL links to whatever "a" is set to. In this specific case, since you specify each possible pseudoclass, it essentially doesn't matter whether you say "a:link" or just "a"

So in the first group, where you write out all the pseudoclasses (a:link, a:visited, etc), you are specifying the CSS for each possible case WITHIN "a"

```
a:link    { color: red }     //set unvisited links to red 
a:visited { color: blue }    //set visited links to blue
a:hover   { color: yellow }  //set hovered links to yellow
a:active  { color: lime }    //set active links to lime
```

In the second group, where you just write "a", you are actually setting the default CSS for all links to what you write in the first line, then redefining the CSS for the other pseudoclasses

```
a    { color: red }          //set ALL links to red!
a:visited { color: blue }    //hm, never mind, let's set visited links to blue
a:hover   { color: yellow }  //hm, never mind, let's set hovered links to yellow
a:active  { color: lime }    //hm, never mind, let's set active links to lime
```

Comment: `:link` doesn't match *only* unvisited links, it matches **all** links.

Comment: @OdraEncoded `:link` does _not_ always match _all_ links, e.g. `:visited` and `a` have precedence (in that order). `:link` will only match *all* links (to some extent) if neither `:visited` nor `a` are matched. It's therefor more likely that `:link` will match unvisited links 'only'.

Comment: @Wynand `:link` **always matches all links**. `:visited` has a higher precedence, yes, but if there is a `:link` and a `:visited` then **both** are matched and the `:visited` selector effects are applied after the `:link` selector effects. Just like in every other multiple selector match case. In CSS there is no such thing as one selector not matching because another selector exists. http://jsfiddle.net/z9X54/1/

Comment: @OdraEncoded I think we're actually saying the same thing here. I misinterpreted your understanding and had taken it that you suggested that `:link` takes precedence over `:visited`. BTW, I understand the concept of _Cascading_ Style Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

:link is when the link is unvisited. So when there is an anchor with a href attribute and the user have never been on the page behind the anchor.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Quentin Actually, this answer is spot on.

Comment: @Wynand no, it's not, `:link` matches more than unvisited hyperlinks.

Comment: @OdraEncoded It depends. If you're suggesting that `:link` matches both visited and unvisited hyperlinks in _all_ cases, then test it in conjunction with `:visited` and `a`. You should see that nothing 'more' than unvisited hyperlinks is matched.

Answer (score -1):

Selector `:link` is a pseudo-element selector for hyperlinks, any element that is an hyperlink will be matched.  The `a` selector will match "only" anchor elements.

*Normally*, every `a` element is also a hyperlink, and I'm not aware *myself* of any way to create an hyperlink in HTML without using an anchor, so you can probably use either of them in most cases.

However, using only `a` will match anchor elements that are not hyperlinks. For example, an anchor element written this way `<a name=sign-up>Sign up form</a>` will not match the hyperlink pseudo-element `:link` selector but will match the `a` selector.