# css link color styles best practice

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

There are many css-samples for styling color of links.

[html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/) offers such css code for link:

```
a { color: #00e; }
a:visited { color: #551a8b; }
a:hover { color: #06e; }​
```

**Is it good enough for most cases?**

Or maybe better css-code exist for styling color of links?

Comment: LoVe HAte (http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html) used to be the recommendation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That's definitely will suffice in vast majority of cases.

Just keep in mind that the correct order of styles for links is:

```css
a:link           { color: #c00 }  /* unvisited links       */
a:visited        { color: #0c0 }  /* visited links         */
a:hover, a:focus { color: #00c }  /* user hovers, or focus */
a:active         { color: #ccc }  /* active links          */
```

The `outline` might look "ugly" for you, but that's a very important accessibility feature. If you remove that - please take care of providing an alternative way to properly distinguish the current element (bigger/bolder font, high contrast background etc.)

Comment: see difference between `a` and `a:link` selectors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638229/css-alink-vs-just-a-without-the-link-part

Comment: How can we write a:link if pseudoclass :link is not supported?

Comment: @AnastasiosMoraitis can you please specify your use case? where do you need that pseudo class when it's not supported?

Answer (score 5):

I always reset settings that might be different between browsers.

I also like to tag links to external websites differently, by adding an image (similar to the one in the wikipedia).

```
a,
a:link,
a:active,
a:visited,
a:hover {
    color:           #d30;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Links to external websites */
a.external:before {
    content:         url(./pics/external.png);
}
```

Comment: If you remove the default underline it may be impossible to distinguish links from the rest of the text by those who are colour blind, or when using a mono-chrome display (such as an E Ink device).

Comment: @tomasz86: good point. But: I don't know a website that underlines links. Probably because It makes texts (with many links) hard to read. When I was more interested in accessibility, I read that people having problems with colors apply their own stylesheets to websites. Thats why I decided to make websites accessible to most people. Those who need the underlined links will (probably) apply their own styles anyway. What is your experience?

Comment: The UK Government website (https://gov.uk) has links underlined. As for using custom stylesheets, I think it may be useful but only if you're using your private desktop / laptop computer. If you need to rely on mobile devices or public computers, etc. then you're most likely forced to view those websites with their default styles. By the way, adding `a:focus` to `a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}` in the code above would be helpful for keyboard users.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be sure that you are styling links (and not the anchors which are not links), you should use `a:link` instead of `a`.

And you could add `a:active` at the end. Here you have a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).

Answer (score 3):

Never remove that outline, or at least remove it only for a:active. If you do it for all anchors then it will be also removed for a:focus which is used for keyboard navigation. Also relying on hover too much is very bad since hover is not present on touch screens.

I like to have all links easily distinguishable from the rest of the content. This is my personal preference:

**2016 version**

```
/* The order is important! Do not use fixed values like px! Always check contrast between text and background for accessibility! */

a { border-bottom: thin solid;
    color: rgb(0,0,192);
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited { color: rgb(160,0,160); }
a:active { color: rgb(192,0,0); }
a:active, a:focus, a:hover { border-bottom-width: medium; }
```

**2015 version**

```
a { border-bottom: thin solid;
    color: rgb(0,0,192);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited { color: rgb(128,0,128); }
a:active { color: rgb(192,0,0); } /* :active MUST come after :visited */
a:active, a:focus, a:hover { border-bottom-width: medium; }
```

**2014 version**

```
a { border-bottom: 1px solid;
    color: rgb(0,0,166);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited { color: rgb(122,0,122); }
a:active { color: rgb(166,0,0); } /* :active MUST come after :visited */
a:active, a:focus, a:hover { border-bottom: 3px solid; }
```

**2013 version**

```
a { color: rgb(0,0,166);
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited { color: rgb(122,0,122); }
a:hover, a:focus, a:active { border-bottom: 2px solid; }
a:focus, a:active { color: rgb(166,0,0); }
```

Answer (score -3):

i find its always good to add

a { outline: none; }

since some browsers add annoying outlines to links when you click them

Comment: Please don't *just* do that. The ouline is here for accessibility reasons. If you remove it, replace it with something else. See http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes to this. I always did it for design reasons.