# How to change the color of font of hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I having a hyperlink generation like below

```
$element.html(indicator.link(url));
```

but it comes in typical hyperlinks blue color. How can I change the color of the font of this hyperlink in javascript?

Comment: Use CSS for all styling. You could add a class to your jQuery element, where the class has stylings for the links. 

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11955727/864233 for examples of the CSS on the link.

Comment: what's wrong with a good old css selector?

Comment: do you have the id of this element after you create it?

Answer (score 4):

It's best to do this with CSS. JavaScript is for `modifying behavior`, while CSS is used for styling. Using JavaScript for this is highly frowned upon.

That said, this question depends on what type of state the link is in. For unvisited links, use the `:link` pseudoselector.

```css
a:link { color: green; }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.espn.com">Visit ESPN!</a>
```

For links you've already visited, you can now use the `:visited` pseudo-class.

```css
a:visited { color: red; }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">Visit YouTube!</a>
```

For links you are just hovering over, use `:hover`

```css
a:hover { color: pink; }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.pineapplesandoranges.com">Pineapples and Oranges</a>
```

You should absolutely not use JavaScript. But here is the solution for it anyways.

```js
var link = document.getElementById("my-link");

link.style.color = "green";
```

```html
<a id="my-link" href="http://www.zebras.com">Zebras</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$element.html(indicator.link(url));
$element.css('color','#000');
```

Or:

```
$('a').css('color','#000');
```

But this would make all links with a tag turn black.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't change the default color of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

well look like if like you are working with Jquery

One option is with the .css()

```
$element.html(indicator.link(url));
$element.css( "color", "red" );
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't change the default color of the hyperlink.