# How do I change the font color of a link using a css class?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the font color of a link inside a header class. I tried using the code below, but it affected all the links on the page. I've tried different arrangements and can't seem to figure out the correct way.

**CSS Code**

```
#amp-wp-header a:active, a:visited {
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<header id="#top" class="amp-wp-header">
    <div>
    <a href="http://example.com">Title </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: include your page id in your css selector

Comment: You have used ```'#amp-wp-header``` in your CSS but in your markup ```amp-wp-header``` is a class so use ```.amp-wp-header```.

Comment: classes start with a (.) in CSS while ids start with a (#) you have those two mixed up in the code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css link color styles best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955594/css-link-color-styles-best-practice)

Comment: Delete the hash in your id `id="#top"`, the hash is not needed in id-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about specific link states, simply do:

```
.amp-wp-header a {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

The issue with your approach is that the comma separator is used to indicate separate selectors.

When you do:

```
.amp-wp-header a:active, a:visited {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

You're saying:

1. Assign this color to all `a:active elements` under `.amp-wp-header`
2. Assign this color to all `a:visited elements`  (This one tags the whole document)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header.amp-wp-header a:active, 
header.amp-wp-header a:visited, 
header.amp-wp-header a:hover,
header.amp-wp-header a:focus {
   color:#ffffff
}
```

Comment: It's generally considered best practice to **not** specify both tag and class as in `header.amp-wp-header`, because the code will break if he ever decides to use a different tag for the header element, or use that class on some other element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<header id="#top" class="amp-wp-header">
    <div class="spl-for-link">
    <a href="http://example.com">
    Title </a>
    </div>
    </header>

    .spl-for-link a
    {
    color:#ffffff;

    }

    .spl-for-link a:hover,a:focus
    {
    color:#ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: But your `.spl-for-link a` rule will apply the formatting to links within `.spl-for-link` in **any** state. In the second rule, the `spl-for-link a:hover` will do nothing, since the color has already been set in the rule above, and the `a:focus` part will apply the style to **any** focused link anywhere in the document.

Comment: did u changed color for spl-for-link a:hover and also give important to color to override the css.

Answer (score 0):

```
#amp-wp-header a:active, #amp-wp-header a:visited{color:#ffffff;}
#amp-wp-header a:hover,#amp-wp-header a:focus{color:#ffffff;}
```

Comment: Sure, but why would I write it as two separate rules?

Answer (score 0):

First off you are using # which is for ID not for class.

use something like this:

```
.amp-wp-header > div a{
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: But this will apply the color even if the link is not active, visited, hovered, or focused.

Comment: @torazaburo you are right but I just explain the way it can be target rest should be handled accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> but it affected all the links on the page.

```
#amp-wp-header a:active,a:visited{color:#ffffff;}a:hover,a:focus{color:#ffffff;}
```

If you reformat this (and change the `#` to a `.` to designate a class), you get

```
.amp-wp-header a:active,a:visited{color:#ffffff;}
a:hover,a:focus{color:#ffffff;}
```

and you can see clearly that in the second rule you **are** applying the color to **all** hovered or focused links.

In other words, the first `{color:#ffffff}` terminates the rule. The following part starting with `a:hover` is interpreted as an entirely new, separate rule. It is not affected by the `.amp-wp-header` just because it happens to be on the same line.

So you might think the solution would be to rewrite your CSS as one rule, so that the higher-level selector applies to **all** the pseudo-class states:

```
.amp-wp-header a:active, a:visited, a:hover, a:focus {color: #ffffff;}
```

However, this does not work either, because the `.amp-wp-header` applies only to `a:active`. Each member of a "selector group", sometimes called "selector list", the list of selectors separated by commas, is completely **independent**. In other words, the above is exactly equivalent to

```
.amp-wp-header a:active {color: #ffffff;}
a:visited {color: #ffffff;}
a:hover {color: #ffffff;}
a:focus {color: #ffffff;}
```

which will apply the style to **all** visited, hovered, or focused links, not just those inside `.amp-wp-header`. Therefore you need to write it as

```
.amp-wp-header a:active  {color:#ffffff;}
.amp-wp-header a:visited {color:#ffffff;}
.amp-wp-header a:hover   {color:#ffffff;}
.amp-wp-header a:focus   {color:#ffffff;}
```

For which the equivalent is

```
.amp-wp-header a:active, 
.amp-wp-header a:visited,
.amp-wp-header a:hover,
.amp-wp-header a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Note that in future browsers you will be able to use `:matches` as follows:

```
.amp-wp-header a:matches(:active, :visited, :hover, :focus) {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

For more details, see the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:any). For compatibility, see [this chart](http://caniuse.com/#search=matches). At the moment you will need to use vendor-prefixed versions such as `-webkit-any` or `-moz-any`, which makes it less attractive.

Besides understanding how selectors and selector groups work, one lesson here is to format and indent your CSS carefully to help you (and others) see what it means.