# how do I change nav bar links hover and active state

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make nav bar links become italic on hover and also when clicked.

Here's my nav bar html - what css should I add?

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-work"><a href="/">Work</a></li>
  <li class="nav-about"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-contact"><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You left off the opening `<ul>` which would probably be good to use as a way to target these links in CSS, assuming the list has a class or ID indicating it's for your nav. But in general, you want to use `a:hover, a:active { font-style: italic; }` These are called "pseudo classes" btw, and this is a good reference http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css link color styles best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955594/css-link-color-styles-best-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
a:hover, a:active { 
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: You should combine the selectors, no need to define it twice.

Comment: Great suggestion. Just changed it

Comment: @SandipSubedi K this worked, but when it changes to italic, other menu items move...... also, it's working only for hover state, not active state.

Comment: @SandipSubedi   Also, how do I apply this effect only to this nav menu, not across the site i.e. other links won't change to italic on hover.   #nav li a:hover {font-style: italic;
} didn't work...

Comment: @user2277916 I added a new class called nav-main for all of them like below <ul>
  <li class="nav-work nav-main"><a href="/">Work</a></li>
  <li class="nav-about nav-main"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-contact nav-main"><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
.nav-main :hover, .nav-main:active{
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pseudo classes `:hover`, `:active`

```css
a:hover,
a:active {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-about"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-contact"><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows,

```
 #nav li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    font-style: italic;
}

#nav li a:active {
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
}
```