# how to change the default color of a link in html? (a:link)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles

I want to change the default blue color of hyperlinks to green in the following script but I keep getting a pink link.

Can you let me know how can I turn it to green when the link hasn't been clicked? Thanks in advance.

---

What I am looking for is this:

- a) Have a green link when it hasn't been clicked yet
- b) Have a red link when the mouse hovers the link
- c) Have a yellow link when the mouse clicks the link
- d) Have a pink link when AFTER the link has been clicked

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
<style>

a:link {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: pink;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>You can change the default colors of links</p>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp" 

target="_blank">HTML Images</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you copy code from an online school, just use the demos they provide: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: The problem is that demos come with errors themselves ♣♦

Comment: I think your code is probably fine. It worked for me. But you need to understand that the link doesn't turn pink when you click on it, it turns pink if someone has already been to the page, wether through your link or not. So if you have been to the page, it will be pink for you.

Comment: I know. what I am looking for is this:
 
a) Have a green link when it hasn't been clicked yet
b) Have a red link when the mouse hovers the link
c) Have a yellow link when the mouse clicks the link
d) Have a pink link when AFTER the link has been clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css link color styles best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955594/css-link-color-styles-best-practice)

Comment: The behavior you are expecting, IS what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
a:visited {
    color: pink;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

visited links will be colored pink, so if you want visited and normal links to be green then use

```
a:link {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I want normal links to be green and visited links to be pink. ☺

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with ":link" just delete it.

Comment: I deleted it and still getting the pink link

Answer (score 0):

It's illogical. If you define a color (pink) for a visited link, then all visited links becomes pink!

I guess you are trying to do a navbar and show active page right?

so check this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_active