# css what's the whole point of :link

Tags: css

what's the whole point of **:link**? i mean what's the point of applying styles to **a:link** when we can simply apply styles to **a** ?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922643/a-vs-alink-what-is-the-difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It references unvisited links.  a { } does the same thing, but you can also set a:visited, a:active, a:hover.  So its just another way to style the state of the anchor tag.  Here is a working jsfiddle that you can see the difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/wfP2U/

Comment: also applies to anchors without href -- see source: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3358149/alink.htm

Answer (score 3):

`:link` only selects unvisited links. So, in the usual case, you are correct that `:link` is the excluded middle and will inherit any styles from `a`.

Note as well that you could also do the same thing by styling `:link`, `:hover`, and `:active`, while `a` would only affect visited links. There's no reason unvisited links are more or less important than other types of links.

However, let's say you just want to make unvisited links have a yellow background, for some reason, but not visited, hover, and active links.  Which would you rather do?

```
a { background-color: yellow; }
a:visited { background-color: transparent; }
a:hover { background-color: transparent; }
a:active { background-color: transparent; }
```

Or

```
a:link { background-color: yellow; }
```

The CSS designers didn't want to limit anyone from doing such a thing, so that is why `:link` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fact that `:link` only matches unvisited links, some `<a>` elements aren't links at all.  Consider `<a name="something">` with no `href` attribute.